# Libcurl Returns Corrupt Data

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl,   CURLOPT_URL, szURL);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl,   CURLOPT_UPLOAD,0);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl,   CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, s_Write_Data);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl,   CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, s_Progress);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, this);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING, 0L);
```

Above are all my opts for the transfer. The download returns a .tar.gz file which using command line curl or WGET returns absolutely fine, using libcurl the returned data is about 8k short, doing a cmp shows that the 2 files change within the first 10 bytes. Been looking through this for 2 days now with no sign of hope. Tried various different combinations of opts.

s_Write_Data is implemented as:

```
size_t CCurlManager::s_Write_Data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{

    CCurlManager *pThis = reinterpret_cast<CCurlManager *>(userp);
    return pThis->WriteData(buffer, size, nmemb);


}
```

The response header I get from curl verbose:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Mon, 17 Dec 2018 13:56:39 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.13 (Linux/SUSE)

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.20

Content-Length: 393800

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.tar.gz"

Connection: close

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Comment: How is `s_Write_Data` implemented?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I was hoping to find how you actually write the data.. If you open a file in text mode (as opposed to binary), this is the kind of mangling you can expect.

Comment: It's writing to a buffer inside the program that is then written in binary mode to a file. The corruption happens pre-writing to the file.

Comment: Any clue in the HTTP response headers? Notably `Transfer-Encoding`

Comment: taking a look now

Comment: Nothing of Transfer-Encoding, just a HTTP/1.1 200

Comment: Time for an [mcve] then.

Comment: Sadly just seems to be running into the issue with this one request, curl works fine in other scenarios and the server responds with the correct data when asked with other methods. Potentially going to be stuck on this a while

Comment: .... or you could paste the *full* code here and we could help out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with wxString (wxWidgets), wxString(char*, int) creates a string of char* for a maximum of int characters OR until a null char is reached, this is non-standard among most other (char*, int) string constructors which just read for int characters.

Basically my created string in my WriteData function was terminating when a null char was reached.